# Python beginner: how to reduce execution time of this small program?

Tags: python, json

```
import json
with open('data.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)
lis= [row['text'] for row in data['City']['values'] if row['text'].startswith("N")]
lis=sorted(lis)
print lis[:5]
```

and json data is like this:

> `{"City": {"values": [{"text": "Abee|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21774}, {"text": "Acadia Valley|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21775}, {"text": "Acme|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21776}, {"text": "Airdrie|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21777}, {"text": "Alderson|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21778}, {"text": "Alix|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21779}, {"text": "Alliance|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21780}, {"text": "Andrew|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21781}, {"text": "Ardmore|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21782}, {"text": "Ardrossan|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21783}, {"text": "Ashmont|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21784}, {"text": "Athabasca|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21785}, {"text": "Atikameg|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21786}, {"text": "Atmore|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21787}, {"text": "Avenir|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21788}, {"text": "Balzac|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21789}, {"text": "Banff|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21790}, {"text": "Barons|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21791}, {"text": "Barrhead|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21792}, {"text": "Bashaw|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21793}, {"text": "Bassano|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21794}, {"text": "Beaumont|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21795}, {"text": "Beaverlodge|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21796}, {"text": "Beiseker|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21797}, {"text": "Bellevue|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21798}, {"text": "Bellis|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21799}, {"text": "Benalto|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21800}, {"text": "Bentley|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21801}, {"text": "Bergen|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21802}, {"text": "Berwyn|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21803}, {"text": "Big Valley|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21804}, {"text": "Bilby|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21805}, {"text": "Bittern Lake|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21806}, {"text": "Black Diamond|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21807}, {"text": "Blackfalds|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21808}, {"text": "Blackie|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21809}, {"text": "Blairmore|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21810}, {"text": "Blue Ridge|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21811}, {"text": "Bluesky|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21812}, {"text": "Bluffton|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21813}, {"text": "Bon Accord|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21814}, {"text": "Bonnyville|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21815}, {"text": "Bowden|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21816}, {"text": "Bow Island|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21817}, {"text": "Boyle|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21818}, {"text": "Brampton|Alberta|Canada", "state": "AB", "id": 21819}]}}`

any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that needs optimising? A script that simple on data that small will execute in a fraction of a second anyway. What difference will tweaking it make?

Comment: its a task given to me, it was taking 0.35 seconds for complete execution but I've made it like this: import json
with open('data.json') as f:
 data=json.load(f)
print sorted([row['text'] for row in data['City']['values'] if row['text'].startswith("N")][:5]) so it comes to 0.28

Comment: I need to make it below 0.10 :(

Comment: I'm slightly confused. You must have a much larger data set because none of the data you passed matches `row['text'].startswith("N")`.

Comment: Yes, this is the sample data, which I've pasted @AidanKane

Comment: @shaurya_b does my answer solve your question?

Comment: it helps a lot, thank you! @AidanKane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively this is a query - filter by 'N%', sort, limit.

I'd really be asking myself, how is this going to be run and what work can I do upfront so that the time sensitive part of it does as little work as possible?

In your case it's pretty obvious - does that data set change? If it's not every run, then you should preparse it into memory (or at least store as something that's not json). Once you take that approach there are loads of options (like using sqlite with an in memory db).

To compare other methods – let's start with the file contents loaded at least (so we're not profiling disk io).

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Now, your method (we're going to drop the printing bit, because there's not much point profiling that in comparisons):

```
def original(data):
    data = json.loads(data)
    lis = [row['text'] for row in data['City']['values'] if row['text'].startswith("A")]
    lis = sorted(lis)
    return lis[:5]
```

And a different one in which we use regex to work directly with the text:

```
def with_regex(data):
    filtered = [x[9:-1] for x in re.findall('"text": "A[^"]+"', data)]
    return sorted(filtered)[:5]
```

And now to compare:

```
%timeit original(data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.4 µs per loop

%timeit with_regex(data)
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.1 µs per loop
```

So you can do it much (5 times) faster with a regex in this case - but the data would need to be well formatted.

If you profile it you'll see that your version spends all its time in the json decoder. The best thing to do is to make that go away (which I would do by doing it once).

Comment: Can you try `row['text'][0]=='A'`? How about list comprehension vs filter?

Comment: @Aif `x[0] == 'a'` is definitely a bit quicker. The cost in the original version is all in parsing the data from json in the first place.